# Entity Framework with Dynamic Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, dynamic-linq

Using EntityFramework context i need to search with many fields.

The EntityDBContext includes

```
public class Brand
{
    public int BrandID { get; set; }
    public string BrandName { get; set; }
    public string BrandDesc { get; set; }
    public string BrandUrl { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
            public DateTime CreatedDate {get;set;}    
            public DateTime ExpiryDate {get;set;}
    //The product class also contains many fields.(not shown here)
}
```

`var context = new EntityDBContext();`

I would like to search the brand with using the field in Product.
The fields of the product are only known at run time.
How can i build the expression to search the brand using the product fields.
Please see the screenshot.
Thanks,
Binod

[image: User search form]

Comment: What do you mean your Product fields are only known in runtime? You are leaving quite a bit of meaningful info from the code you have given. How are the fields mapped in your model?

Comment: Exactly what you want to achieve and please show the fields which link these two classes.

Comment: If i am not mistaking, then you want to get the brands on the basis of the product, right? Let me know so that i can share the code..

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'm a bit unclear on this part of your question:

`the fields of the product are only known at run time.`
How so? Can you elaborate on this, because I don't see a working implementation of this using EF. What is your database table (`Products` presumably) set up for? What properties are in that class?

We need to know that before we can give you an **accurate answer**. However, I'll give you a more general example, maybe that helps you in understanding.

```
var all_brands_that_sell_shoes = /* But not always ONLY shoes */
        myDataContext.Brands
                     .Where(brand =>
                                 brand.Products.Any(product =>
                                                          product.Type == "Shoe")
                            )
                     .ToList();
```

**Edit**

If I re-read your question, you don't mean that the `Product` class' properties are not know until runtime; but that you don't know in advance which filters need to be applied and which need to be skipped?

This second answer assumes that is what you want. Again, I don't know your class' properties since you didn't post them, so I'm inventing my own fields for the sake of example.

First, make an object like below. This will be used to aggregate all filters you wish to apply to the selection:

```
public class MySearchCriteria
{
    public string ProductName_Contains   { get; set; }
    public int    ProductWeight_LessThan { get; set; }
    public int    ProductType_Id         { get; set; }
}
```

When you want to filter the list, you pass a `MySearchCriteria` object to the method:

```
public List<Brand> GetFilteredList(MySearchCriteria filters)
{
    var brands = myDataContext.Brands; //All brands (for now)

    if(filters.ProductType_Id > 0)
    {
          //IF the filter has a value, filter the list accordingly:
          brands = brands.Where(brand => brand.Products.Any(product => product.TypeId == filters.ProductType_Id);
    }

    if(filters.ProductWeight_LessThan > 0)
    {
          //IF the filter has a value, filter the list accordingly:
          brands = brands.Where(brand => brand.Products.Any(product => product.Weight < filters.ProductWeight_LessThan));
    }

    if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filters.ProductName_Contains))
    {
          //IF the filter has a value, filter the list accordingly:
          brands = brands.Where(brand => brand.Products.Any(product => product.Name.Contains(filters.ProductName_Contains)));
    }

     return brands.ToList();
}
```

This method makes sure that the list was filtered according to the `SearchCriteria` you provided.

If you didn't use the field `filters.ProductName_Contains` for example, it would be an empty string, and the if-evaluation would've prevented you from filtering based on an empty string. In the end, you would not have applied a name-based filter.

I hope this is the answer you were looking for? If not, please elaborate more as I'm having trouble understanding what it is you want then.

Comment: What you have written in above **product.Type** the type is field of class Product. The use select the any fields such as Type or Product Name or CreatedDate ..etc and the appropriate value with respective to it.
The query data i want is any field in Product.Type with its respective value.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: my mention of `product.type` was an example. Since you didn't post the class' contents, I don't know what is and isn't in there. But reading your comment, did you mean that **the fields you'll want to filter one are only known at runtime** or that **the class' properties are only known at runtime**? I think everyone responding is assuming the second option, which is to an extent nonsensical. If the first option is correct (you want to filter on some of the fields, but not always), I can give you the answer you probably need.

Comment: he fields I will want to filter one are only known at runtime
Please see the picture that i have added.

Comment: @Anzeo: Check update. That's what I was expecting to give as an answer, but was waiting for confirmation from OP.